# Installed Strom on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

I want to set up storm 'open source' on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I tried the following method but failed:

Unpack Storm release, and put the unpacked bin/directory on your PATH and make sure the bin/storm script is executable.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering as OP mentioned his question.

@OP as you said , unpack storm release means Its a TAR ( most of the cases ) or RAR archive. so unpack it means

```
tar -xvf <here_place_your storm location_path>
```

Then put it it on your PATH as from where you would like to call it.

Then

make the storm script executable. i.e

```
chmod +x <path_to _your_strom script>
```